# Is there any other way to share react components across projects without using npm, rush and bit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, bit.dev, rush

I want to share react components across different projects. I tried rush but it is not working properly apart from that we can't use npm.

I tried rush.js but it is not working properly and we can't use npm, bit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS CodeArtifacts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/welcome.html) to publish your packages. You can have npm as your upstream registry, so that any package which is not present in codeArtifacts will be resolved from npm registry.